# What are the issues when performing an ANCOVA with a covariate that is influenced by experimental manipulation?

Tags: statistical-power, ancova

#### Context:

I am doing a study on lying.

- The independent variable was manipulated such that participants were either told to **lie** or **tell the truth**.
- The dependent variable is related to the amount of detail provided and is extracted from the text provided by participants(this is a standard system of deception detection called reality monitoring).

#### Issue:

I noticed that much of the previous research (e.g., Sporer [2000]) has included or suggested the use of  word count as a covariate to make sure that any differences in the number of details do not simply reflect differences in the number of words. 
However, I was under the impression that covariates needed to be measured before the experimental manipulation and should not be related to the independent variable. 
Word count is measured after people have provided their truthful or deceptive account (And possibly related to truthfulness since people might provide more details by giving a longer account). I have read Miller and Chapman's paper on the misunderstanding of ANCOVA ([FREE PDF](http://dionysus.psych.wisc.edu/Lit/Articles/MillerG2001a.pdf)).

#### Questions

- Does including word count as a covariate looking at the effect of condition on details provided reduce statistical power?
- Is it meaningful to include a covariate that is measured after, and is assumed to be affected by, an experimental manipulation?
- How serious is violation of heterogeneity of covariance when including covariates?
- Rather than including word length as a covariate, often authors calculate number of details say per 100 words and then perform their analyses as normal. how is this different to including word length as a covariate?

#### Additional References:

For those interested, references include:

- Stromwall, L., & Granhag, A. (2005). Children's repeated lies and truths: effects on adults' judgements and reality monitoring scores. Psychiatry, Psychology and Law, 12(2), 345-356,
- Vrij, A., Mann, S., Fisher, R., Leal, S., Milne, R., & Bull, R. (2008b). Increasing Cognitive Load to Facilitate Lie Detection: The Benefit of Recalling an Event in Reverse Order. Law and Human Behavior, 32(3), 253-265.
- Sporer, S. L. (2004). Reality monitoring and the detection of deception. In P. A. Granhag & L. Stromwall (Eds.), The detection of deception in forensic contexts. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Comment: What is your measure of the number of details?  By word length do you mean number of words?

Comment: Links to references would be helpful in getting our heads around this.  Also, please clarify the nature of the covariates & the response variables.  This is a bit too abstract at the moment.

Comment: yes, number of words. the 5 response variables are 5 types of details (space, time, vision, sound and emotion). for example the sentence "the book was on the table" contains one spatial detail, 2 visual details, no sound/emotion/time details. it's all a bit theoretical (which i didn't want to bore you with). my independent variables are truthfulness (some accounts are made up and some are true) and recall (some people have already recounted the event before and others have not). it's an experiment (With random allocation).

Comment: oh and ps. sorry about no references, none of them are accessible for free for your guys (i get them through my university library)

Comment: Some of us can access university libraries, too.  :)  And some of us may go one better: we may already have the PDF or book.  ;-)  A citation is helpful enough.

Comment: Given the update: I would say "sentence length" or "expression length"; in many other contexts, word length = # of characters, sentence length = # words.  It's unfortunate that ambiguity exists, but that's life.

Comment: hm that's a good tip for writing my paper! thanks. and a citation: everyone uses different ways of defining the types of details i am scoring for but two examples are: Stromwall, L., & Granhag, A. (2005). Children's repeated lies and truths: effects on adults' judgements and reality monitoring scores. Psychiatry, Psychology and Law, 12(2), 345-356, AND Vrij, A., Mann, S., Fisher, R., Leal, S., Milne, R., & Bull, R. (2008b). Increasing Cognitive Load to Facilitate Lie Detection: The Benefit of Recalling an Event in Reverse Order. Law and Human Behavior, 32(3), 253-265.

Comment: i am not using cognitive operations though... Sporer, S. L. (2004). Reality monitoring and the detection of deception. In P. A. Granhag & L. Stromwall (Eds.), The detection of deception in forensic contexts. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.
 That's the one that talks about controlling for word length a LOT :)

Comment: 1. If you're doing a study of lying, why wouldn't lying/truthtelling be the dependent variable?  2. You expressed a concern about power, but I think the more relevant concern would be that one variable (let's call it "expression length") would be part and parcel of the other (degree of detail), rather than truly being a separate variable that could be tested for its plausibility as a cause.

Comment: no lying is the independent variable, they are instructed to lie or tell the truth. the dependent variable is the volume of detail provided in truthful and deceptive statements.

Comment: AHA!!! So you want to know if they are giving more details & are more talkative or reserved when lying (or telling the truth)?

Comment: sorry.i was obviously not very clear in my question! i am looking at whether they provide more details (dependent variable) when telling the truth than lying (the independent variable). the number of words they include was purely of interest as a COVARIATE rather than a dependent variable. I was just worried about including number of words as a covariate because it is so closely related to the independent variable (ie. people also tend to provide more words when telling the truth).

Comment: oh, and i should probably also mention i am using MANOVA in spss...

Comment: @Anita, I performed a huge overhaul of the question to incorporate all the content in the comments (e.g., listing references; clear description of experiment; clear articulation of the question). Feel free to tweak if I have misconstrued anything.

Comment: thanks heaps jeromy. that's right. there is one more question i have (related): how serious is violation of heterogeneity of covariance when including covariates? thanks! anita

Comment: @jeremy: thanks for the rewrite.  Were I starting without the Miller & Chapman paper, I would think it premature to suggest ANCOVA.  I'm not yet sold on the linearity; ANCOVA and the like are often misapplied anyway, and I look forward to examining the M&C paper. To the OP (Anita): in the literature, do they tend to use linear models or ANCOVA?  There may be a transform applied to the # of words (e.g. a logarithmic transformation).  If you can check or, even better, post details on common models used, that could help.

Comment: Channeled my inner @jeremy and added the question.  :)  To Anita (the OP), if anything else comes up - I think you're also allowed to edit your question - there's a little button underneath the question box.

Comment: interesting. well in two of the papers i can find (the granhag & stromwall 2005 paper mentioned above and another one), they calculated the volume of detail per 100 words spoken then put it in a MANOVA- so that's not using ancova... it's adjusting for the effects of a covariate on the dependent variable before you put it in the anova. what is the difference between adjusting for the effects of a covariate before you run the analysis and just adding a covariate?

Comment: That would be good to include in your original question - it'll get harder to answer things in the comments.  :)

Answer (score 2):

[Update / Note: Answer may be revised in light of ANCOVA questions.]

This is both an answer and a clarification.  It seems like the OP is asking about studying $\textrm{E}(NumDetails | (Honesty, NumWords))$ (so to speak), where $NumDetails$ is the # of details provided, $NumWords$ is the number of words used and $Honesty$ is 0 or 1, based on whether or not the person is telling the truth.

In simple terms, the interest is on the conditional distribution (or expectation) of the number of details provided by the subject conditioned on both whether they are telling the truth and if they are particularly loquacious.

This is reasonable, but has a slight hitch: if loquaciousness is related to their honesty, then it may be helpful to find a relationship for that.  In any case, the number of details would generally have to be related to the number of words used to express the ideas.

To answer the basic question: It's not really so easy to say that it reduces power, because the question seems to be on the # of details, not on the detection of lying.

An implicit question is whether or not the number of words is a reasonable covariate.  It is.  It may be dependent on both the subject and the role they're asked to play.  You should investigate whether or not it has some dependence on the role (lying or honest), and, if the subject is measured repeatedly, the dependence on the subject.

With these in hand, you can address whether you get more details per, say, 100 words when they are lying versus when they are not.  You could stratify based on discrete intervals, such as 0-50 words, 51-100, etc. (or larger ranges), or based on quantiles (e.g. bottom quintile, 20-40%ile, and so on).  This way you may not need a formulaic model that estimates the distribution of # of words and # of details conditioned on the role and subject.